# CLLocation update continuously in when app in background/suspend state

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have been working in corelocation framework to fetch current location i'm getting location when my app in foreground state.

Now my question is when my app goes to suspend state/background state i want to get the current location for every 'n' minutes.This condition was not satisfied so please help me here i'm struggling lot here..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This says it all https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

You should register your app for background location updates by adding `location` to the `UIBackgroundModes` key in your app's Info.plist file ([see docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10)).
iOS will send your app location updates is it thinks it is necessary. When your app is in the background, you can't execute functions that poll for location every n minutes.

Comment: ok but when app goes to background/suspend mode my update method was not called.